# Neo4j: Cypher match where node has property OR has relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious here but just to be sure. Starting with this query:

```
match (e:Event), (u:User)
where (e.status = 'public' XOR (e)<-[:`can_access`*1..2]-(u) AND u.id = '541c7a8797b272f708000001')
return e
```

That returns all events that are either public or accessible by up to two degrees from the user across the "can_access" relationship. It works as expected.

Is this the best way to approach this? I'm unable to use a relationship identifier in the `where` clause, so I'll theoretically take a performance hit over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing it looks fine, but if you're looking for alternative suggestions, you could do this.   The main thing is to move most of your `WHERE` into the `MATCH` block instead:

```
MATCH (e:Event {status: "public"})
RETURN e

UNION

MATCH (e:Event)<-[:`can_access`*1..2]-(u:User {id: '541c7a8797b272f708000001'})
RETURN e;
```

Now, this ignores your `XOR` bit, so I suppose it's possible something is both public, and accessible via `can_access`.  In that case, your query would exclude such a result, and mine would include it.  But based on the semantics of your query, I'm guessing this is OK and you didn't really need the `XOR`.  If the `XOR` is important, then you could always separately weed out the nodes that happen to meet both criteria, or otherwise fix the linkages so both conditions don't simultaneously hold.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, I'll play with this. Are you sure that mine would exclude events that are both public and accessible? I think my query would only match it once. In my specs, that scenario does pass. It's possibly my specs are wrong, of course. ;-)

Comment: That's what XOR does.   (True XOR True) => False.  So in your query, if the event has status=public **AND** your user is linked to it via can_access, then it wouldn't be returned.  I wasn't sure if that's what you intended (the use of XOR is peculiar here) - I just want to point it out as a potential tripping point.

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood it, then. And no, that isn't what I wanted. If an event is both public AND the user has a `can_access` link, they most definitely should be able to get into it! I'll review my code now. Really appreciate the help!